# Ubuntu 18.04 won't wake after screen lock and blank / suspend / sleep

Tags: ubuntu, suspend, screen-lock, keyboard-event

I am trying to run Ubuntu 18.04 on a laptop with an AMD A12 processor and Radeon R7 graphics. I am having nothing but problems and am very discouraged with Ubuntu though I used 12.04 for years without such problems.

I have two problems that are maddening, and I will post them separately. The problems happen only on Gnome and Ubuntu on Xorg and do not happen on Wayland. However, I am told that it's best not to run Gnome on Wayland.

This problem is that the computer sometimes doesn't wake up from suspend. Well, I think it does wake up because the optical drive spins and the hard drive ticks away, but I cannot login because the lock screen is a hash of colors or a distorted background without a place to login. I cannot even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a prompt. All input is frozen.

I am wondering if Xorg is configured correctly. I am running the Oilaf video driver which works well under Wayland so I don't know if there is a problem with Xorg and that driver.

Comment: May be duplicate to the question with this answer that worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1041397/413258

Comment: Do you use full disk encryption (LUKS) suggested by Ubuntu during fresh install?  `crypsetup` may is waiting for a password but that fact is not visible on locked/blanked screen. Asking because of bug reports of the swap itself being encrypted creating a chicken-and-egg issue. See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1774950 affecting many users.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029405/ubuntu-18-04-crashes-on-resuming-from-suspend

Comment: I did this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/561796/314643
make sure to have xScreenSaver

Comment: For some people landing here, including those running Ubuntu 22.04 on Dell laptops, the problem may actually be Wayland. See my answer here: [Wayland window manager causes my computer to stay on a black/blank screen and not wake up](https://askubuntu.com/a/1470563/327339). I first tried the [fix here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/500111/114401), and it didn't fix it for me. Then I found the 3 fixes in my answer, including turning off Wayland and going back to the X11 window manager, and that's what worked best.

Answer (score 36):

There seems to be an issue with nouveau driver. Edit the `grub` file by editing it with sudo access.

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the line that says `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` so that it finally looks like this `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"`

Then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot after successfully updating `grub`.

Comment: Does this mean `GRUB_CMD_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"`?

Comment: Yes @ClarkHenry, you need to set `GRUB_CMD_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"`

Comment: what helped me was to set `nouveau.blacklist=1`.

Comment: after doing so, resolution is not set properly.

Comment: Why would modifying the nouveau (open source NVIDIA drivers) have any impact on a machine using an AMD Radeon graphics card?

Comment: It worked for me.

Comment: Works great. With me it was an external monitor that would not "wake up" when the computer was woken up...

Comment: @Twirrim have only intel integrated graphics and it helped anyway

Comment: This seems to have fixed my zorin installation that was experiencing lock screen freezing which was requiring me to reboot the machine on lock.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Fixed the problem on Ubuntu 20.04 with nvidia gfx. Thanks!

Comment: it does not work for me

Comment: See also: [Ask Ubuntu: Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't wake up after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/a/1298222/327339)

Answer (score 8):

The Screen Saver helped me with Xubuntu 18.04 - except I installed xscreensaver and everything started working correctly.

Answer (score 5):

To repair this instance, i typed:

```
sudo apt install gnome-screensaver
```

And it worked first time. I don't know why the file wasn't working or why it wasn't there, but like i said... worked for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Wow I'd been living with this issue for months and this fixed it for me instantly.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem, on lock screen it would turn off the video signal but would not turn back on.

If you try to blindly type your password, you might notice that screen turns on and logs in.

It was a video / screen saver related issue.

**I fixed it by installing xScreenSaver**

Comment: This but doing this also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/561796/314643

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer to this at long last. It seems to be working so far, but it's just been a few days. The solution I came across is to:

```
sudo gdm3 -reset
```

and reboot.

(Note: After the gdm3 reset, it's going to come back to a login screen that won't let you login. Don't worry about it. Reboot and it will return to the normal login screen and everything will be fine.)

Comment: I am receiving the prompt 'Failed to parse options: Unknown option -reset'  Any idea why?

Comment: Same error as @RonPiggott

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I got the error mentioned above and made a question for it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/488037/gdm3-failed-to-parse-options-unknown-option-reset-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: I got the same error, but `sudo killall gdm3` worked for me (it kills gdm3, which is then restarted, and the screen unblanks).

Comment: On 19.10, `sudo gdm3 -reset` doe not seem to work. The comment above was more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I am having a very similar issue on an HP Pavilion 17-ar050wm laptop.  I've tried lots of different things -- using Oilaf/Ubuntu-X bleeding-edge drivers, switching to `lightdm`, running `gdm3 -reset` -- but the only thing that seems to make a difference is whether I entered sleep by pressing the power button or by closing the laptop lid.  When I just closed the lid, the screen/keyboard doesn't come back up properly about 3/4 of the time, but when I pressed the button first, it comes back up 100% of the time (so far).

So for lack of a better solution, I'm just going to try to remember to press the power button every time before I close the lid.

Answer (score 2):

**Ubuntu 21.10 NVIDIA 470/510 `nv_restore_user_channels` bug**

This started happening to me as soon as I moved to Ubuntu 21.10 on my Lenovo ThinkPad P51 NVIDIA Quadro M1200, and based on kernel traces, it is this exact bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-510/+bug/1946303 My duplicated investigation: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-510/+bug/1953674

To reproduce the problem easily, I had to disconnect the power cable from my laptop and be on battery only. Otherwise, the problem would only happen sometimes, and more commonly after suspending for a few hours.

Workarounds:

- (tested for several days now, seems to be working) the bug report links to https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/fixed-suspend-resume-issues-with-the-driver-version-470/187150/3 from heroic user humblebee which has workaround:

  ```
  sudo systemctl stop nvidia-suspend.service
  sudo systemctl stop nvidia-hibernate.service
  sudo systemctl stop nvidia-resume.service

  sudo systemctl disable nvidia-suspend.service
  sudo systemctl disable nvidia-hibernate.service
  sudo systemctl disable nvidia-resume.service

  sudo mv /lib/systemd/system-sleep/nvidia ~/nvidia.bak
  ```

  and reboot.

  In case you nuke it, the contents of `nvidia.bak` are:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  case "$1" in
      post)
          /usr/bin/nvidia-sleep.sh "resume"
          ;;
  esac
  ```

  That post gives their root cause:

  > the 470 driver migrated to systemd method while previous versions relied on Kernel Driver Callback. Apparently this is broken on some setups and kernels.
- PURGE EVERYTHING FROM NVIDIA: uninstall all nvidia packages (`dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia`, `sudo apt uninstall`), and purge their configs as well (`sudo apt purge ...`). But then you have no acceleration.

  Note that even non graphic stuff like NVIDIA's CUDA/OpenCL package was still breaking things, notably I couldn't suspend after removing the graphics but keeping them, related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133919/ubuntu-18-04-2-immediately-wakes-up-from-suspend/1363662#1363662

It is easy to know if you've hit the same bug or not, just look for the following stack traces on your dmesg.

Because you are likely shutting down the computer and restarting, you have to look for them in the dmesg of the previous boot as per https://askubuntu.com/questions/765315/how-to-find-previous-boot-log-after-ubuntu-16-04-restarts :

```
journalctl -b-1
```

The traces are:

```
WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 18016 at /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.47.03/build/nvidia/nv.c:3935 nv_restore_user_channels+0xce/0xe0 [nvidia]

Call Trace:
<TASK>
nv_set_system_power_state+0x22b/0x3e0 [nvidia]
nv_procfs_write_suspend+0xe9/0x140 [nvidia]
proc_reg_write+0x5a/0x90
? __cond_resched+0x1a/0x50
vfs_write+0xc3/0x250
ksys_write+0x67/0xe0
__x64_sys_write+0x19/0x20
do_syscall_64+0x61/0xb0
? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x37/0xb0
? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
? __x64_sys_newfstatat+0x1c/0x20
? do_syscall_64+0x6e/0xb0
? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
? do_syscall_64+0x6e/0xb0
? asm_exc_page_fault+0x8/0x30
entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xae
```

```
WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 18016 at /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/510.47.03/build/nvidia/nv.c:4152 nv_set_system_power_state+0x2d0/0x3e0 [nvidia]

nv_procfs_write_suspend+0xe9/0x140 [nvidia]
proc_reg_write+0x5a/0x90
? __cond_resched+0x1a/0x50
vfs_write+0xc3/0x250
ksys_write+0x67/0xe0
__x64_sys_write+0x19/0x20
do_syscall_64+0x61/0xb0
? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x37/0xb0
? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
? __x64_sys_newfstatat+0x1c/0x20
? do_syscall_64+0x6e/0xb0
? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
? do_syscall_64+0x6e/0xb0
? asm_exc_page_fault+0x8/0x30
entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xae
```

I was also seeing the following ACPI error:

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC.HKEY.DEVT.PEGS], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)

No Local Variables are initialized for Method [DEVT]

Initialized Arguments for Method [DEVT]:  (1 arguments defined for method invocation)
  Arg0:   00000000fe968048 <Obj>           Integer 00000000000000D3

ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC.HKEY.DEVT due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
```

Related:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371055/ubuntu-21-10-resume-produces-blank-screen
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368673/suspend-not-working-ubuntu-20-04-does-not-work-at-all-21-10in-battery-mode
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345073/suspend-not-working-properly-cannot-wake-up-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-nvidia
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362001/ubuntu-21-04-wont-wake-from-sleep
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369652/getting-suspend-to-work-on-ubuntu-21-10-impish-release
- https://superuser.com/questions/1699286/ubuntu-21-10-suspension-problems
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_36yNWw_07g
- https://itsfoss.community/t/ubuntu-21-10-not-reawakening-from-sleep/7782

Comment: Disabling the systemctl nvidia services and then removing the script file as instructed here seemed to fix my issue. Desktop Ubuntu 20.04, NVidia 710 graphics, wouldn't wake from *long* sleep (though short sleep wake worked fine), now appears to be fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My machine had a similar issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04. After closing the lid, the OS wouldn't wake up, but the backlight would come on. (Possibly unrelated: it appeared my keyboard was unresponsive as well, since toggling caps lock didn't light up the LED.)

I found a fix in my bios settings. There was a checkbox for enabling wake-up when the laptop lid is opened. It was unchecked, but checking it fixed the problem.

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-21-lowlatency

$ lsb_release -r
Release:    18.04

$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
Model name:          AMD PRO A10-8700B R6, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G

$ dmidecode
BIOS Information
    Vendor: HP
    Version: N73 Ver. 01.17
    Release Date: 11/02/2016
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was with `lightdm` and I was able to fix the blank screen after locking issue by simply switching to `gdm3`:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm3
```

When prompted during install, change from `lightdm` to `gdm3` and hit enter.  A reboot is necessary and you'll now have a more modern login screen.  Most importantly, waking up from locking the screen actually works now, at least for me it finally does.

---

Also, if you're sick of being stuck while testing all these various solutions, use the keyboard combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or any session from <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>) to switch to a terminal session then switch back via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.  You should now see text saying your screen is locked but just give it 5 seconds and you'll see the password prompt.  That saved me a lot of headaches having to forcibly restart each various solution I tried.

Comment: On a ThinkPad (x390), the key combination workaround is 
FN+CTRL+ALT+F2 (Terminal session) and 
FN+CTRL+ALT+F7 (back to GUI)

Comment: `gdm3` works better and faster than `lightdm` for me!

Answer (score 1):

Default driver for AMD cards is called `amdgpu` - https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/AMDGPU (NOT nouveau, nouveau is a default NVIDIA open source driver).

What fixed the issue for me was setting the value of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` to the `"amdgpu.dc=0"` in the grub config file. (why that? Some suggest because of some [kernel bug](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/what-is-kernel-parameter-amdgpu-dc-0-doing-and-why-do-i-suddenly-need-it/32813), didn't investigate it)

In steps:

1. Open grub config: `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`
2. Set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="amdgpu.dc=0"` and save
3. Run `sudo update-grub`
4. After successful update, reboot.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation:

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-33-generic

$ lsb_release -r
Release: 18.04

$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               55
Model name:          Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU N3540  @ 2.16GHz
Stepping:            8
CPU MHz:             880.243
CPU max MHz:         2665,6001
CPU min MHz:         499,8000
BogoMIPS:            4331.60
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           24K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            1024K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat

$ sudo dmidecode | grep BIOS -A2
BIOS Information
Vendor: Acer
Version: V1.10
BIOS Revision: 0.0
Firmware Revision: 1.9
```

Hardware - `Aser E5-511-P6CS`

Solution is remove from grub `$vt_handoff` string.

To do this - just edit `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` file.

Set `$vt_handoff = "1"` to `$vt_handoff = "0"`

Comment: Do you mean change `vt_handoff="1"` to `vt_handoff="0"`? The way you wrote it is the syntax for a comparison, rather than assignment. Not sure if others' grub files are different, but there are multiple comparisons in mine...seems to make more sense to change the assignment toward the beginning of the file.

Comment: vt_handoff tells which virtual console to invoke. If on a black screen you can switch to different console then may be this solves problem but if your os is frozen then not sure this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issues. Tried disable switchable graphics card and modified vt_handoff. None of them worked.

Then I "accidentally" fixed the problem by setting the SATA mode to be "ACHI" (was "IDE" when I installed ubuntu) in the BIOS. And it fixed the problem!

Comment: Instead of continuing a thread here (since there's no way for people to reply with Answers to your Answer), it'd be better to Answer this question (with the first 2 paragraphs) and then open a New Question with your 3rd paragraph. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and resolved it by updating to the latest mainline kernel (4.20) from the Ubuntu published one (4.15) using the Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility (aka Ukuu).

At first I thought it might be a display driver problem, so I downgraded to nvidia-390, but it persisted. Completely disappeared after updating to 4.20 kernel though.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, disabling "automatic suspend" for both when plugged in and on battery solved the problem. 
I noticed after installing updates, setting changed again by itself, keep that in mind.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Ubuntu 18 and dell amd ryzen laptop) closing lid during day works fine, but when I close lid and open it next day, usually I see black screen with backlight when press power button to wake up (lid does not work). So at the moment the solution is that:

- wake laptop with power button
- it wakes but no lockscreen, only backlight
- close lid to suspend
- open lid to resume

Answer (score 0):

here is similar problem with a solution that i have applied after couple hours to make it work:
https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/Dell-Latitude-7390-and-Ubuntu-20-04-quot-Suspend-quot-barely/m-p/7581922#M17265

edit: it is about adding to grub linux cmdline in /etc/default/grub this property:

```
snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0
```

followed by

```
mem_sleep_default=deep
```

and after a day i think it was just a luck that suspend started working aftere these changes, but it done something because before 100% of suspends needed reboot and after these sometimes it suspends fine **however now i uninstalled pm-utils and swapped gdm3 with lightdm and it works for now.**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with a Thinkpad and tried many things to no avail.
But there's a BIOS setting in mine, under the power menu, for the sleep mode. Windows 10 was selected and I switched it to Linux and I'm having no problems with it at all so far.

Answer (score 0):

For users of the latest AMD models, there is an important fix in the kernel. [Updating the kernel to 5.15](https://github.com/milkovsky/Linux-on-Lenovo-Slim-7-Carbon-AMD/blob/main/README.md#kernel-update-to-515) fixed the problem for me on my  [Lenovo Yoga 7 Carbon with Ubuntu 21.10](https://github.com/milkovsky/Linux-on-Lenovo-Slim-7-Carbon-AMD/blob/main/README.md#suspend)

Answer (score 0):

in my case was solved by installing the nvidia driver

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-465
```

Also in the UEFI:

Turn off the secure boot and change the sleep mode from Windows10 to Linux

Laptop: Lenovo ThinkPad P14s