# gdm3: Failed to parse options: Unknown option -reset (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: gnome3, suspend, screen-lock, sleep

I'm having the same issue as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442057/ubuntu-18-04-wont-wake-after-screen-lock-and-blank-suspend-sleep): my computer won't wake up after I lock the screen or put it to sleep. One of the answers suggests running `sudo gdm3 -reset`, which I tried. But just as some in the comments noted, I get *Failed to parse options: Unknown option -reset*.

I thought this deserved its own question. A quick search didn't turn up anything mentioning this specific error, and I don't know enough about `gdm3` to troubleshoot this on my own effectively.

Here are the last several lines of `sudo strace gdm3 -reset`, in case that's helpful:

```
access("/etc/selinux/config", F_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
futex(0x7f618a840f38, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7f618a840f38, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [USR1], NULL, 8) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10281936, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 10281936, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f61862dc000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2995, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2995
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/gdm.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/gdm.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/gdm.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/gdm.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/gdm.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/gdm.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/gdm.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/gdm.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/gdm.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/gdm.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/gdm.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/gdm.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
futex(0x7f618a840f38, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7f618a840f38, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/glib20.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/charset.alias", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "Failed to parse options: Unknown"..., 47Failed to parse options: Unknown option -reset
) = 47
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

It seems to be looking for something in that cascade of files (something that defines `-reset`, perhaps?), and giving up when none of those files exists. Should they?

Any suggestions much appreciated. Thanks!

### Edit: specs!

```
  uname -r
4.15.0-42-generic
  lsb_release -r
Release:    18.04
  lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              8
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               158
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
Stepping:            9
CPU MHz:             3938.907
CPU max MHz:         4200.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            7200.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-7
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp
```

...and yes, I did put a Christmas tree in my bash prompt.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't worry about a command that may or may not fix your issue (looks to be invalid, especially since multiple others couldn't use it successfully).  There were MANY recommendations in that thread (and many, many more on google) for your core problem.  I would change course and try heading down a different path.  If you insist on "resetting" gdm3, just reinstall the package.....

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/GNOME/gdm/blob/master/daemon/main.c#L316) are all the three options that `gdm3` has in all their glory, but as you can see `reset` isn't one. It's quite possible the answer you are referring to got the command wrong or somewhat less likely the code was refactored and the option removed, but either way it would be best to ping the person who suggested it and then move on to solve the actual problem you've got rather than waste your time trying to understand why a solution that doesn't work for anyone but one person doesn't work for you either.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that the [last commit](https://github.com/GNOME/gdm/commit/d8a9dafa736742a0532ea54f7a25ef302778c6d8#diff-1fff9aaa41fac5c2ac6eba7ebe71f11b) in that file prevents gdm from ignoring unknown options. That means that most likely `-reset` was never an option, but until recently it was discarded without an error making it *look* like it was a valid option. What that means to you is that instead of `gdm3 -reset` you just need to run `gdm3` without any options for the same effect.

Comment: @undercat Nice digging!  Not to mention standard dictates that "if" it ever had existed, it would be gdm3 --reset (two hyphens).  That was the big red flag in the second sentence of the OP's post. :)

Comment: @undercat yeah, I tried the other options before posting this :) ...anyway, good find! I will try that when I get back to work laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restarting it using their service?

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that in its current form your post looks like troubleshooting advice rather than a definitive answer. If that was not intended, please edit the post to make the explanation clearer. Otherwise, it might be best placed as a comment under the original question.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to run `sudo gdm3` and it immediately fixed the mentioned issue with the suspend. Unfortunately this messed up everything else!

First trackpad, then keyboard were not working. Had to boot from recovery mode and update the `grub`. After that and uninstalling `gdm3` everything is working fine.