# Pop! OS wakes up from suspend with a black screen

Tags: suspend, sleep, touch-screen

Release: 20.04, Gnome. Without grub. On a Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5 (2020) 2-in-1. I found this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442057/ubuntu-18-04-wont-wake-after-screen-lock-and-blank-suspend-sleep) advising to edit the grub file, but this distro doesn't have grub. Is there a similar file I could edit instead? Or would it work if I were to install grub?

Answer (score 0):

5.7 was the right kernel!
Now I can put the laptop in Suspend, and it will wake up without a black screen!