# Ubuntu 20.04 laptop wake-up fix makes computer run hot, shortens battery life by at least half

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, suspend, laptop, nouveau

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Gigabyte Aero 15 Classic-SA and it has the problem that, when I close the lid the gnome desktop environment crashes -- the screen is black except for a little dash in the upper left hand corner blinking. I can restart with `Ctrl-Alt-F2`, entering my login information, then running `sudo systemctl restart gdm.service`.

A solution is given by [this SE post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/500111/496400). This solves the problem of the laptop not waking from suspend properly, but it causes the laptop to run *extremely* hot, even when the lid is shut (in fact it crashed when it was closed in my backpack), and shortens the battery life from ~8 hours to something like 2 hours.

I switched it back (that is, deleted the line from the grub file and updated grub) and it went back to normal -- long battery life, cool running, crash on suspend.

Anyone have any idea why this might be happening? And if so, what I might be able to do to fix both problems? As a side note, it suspends properly when I do `sudo pm-suspend` and then close the lid, so maybe there is a workaround to have it run that command on suspend?

Comment: What behavior do you get from `systemctl suspend`?

Comment: @FelixJN In this order: the screen goes black with backlight turned off; backlight turns on with blinking dash in the upper left-hand side of the screen; screen turns back on to the magenta Ubuntu lock screen with my profile. From the lock screen, I am not able to move my mouse or type on the keyboard, so I have to do a hard power off -- I suspect that they keyboard and mouse drivers are failing to load.

Answer (score 0):

One solution was given by [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1345073/1458057). All I had to do was change my graphics card driver from the Nouveau open source driver to the Nvidia 470 driver in the Additional Drivers menu.

That said, I would ideally like to use the open source drivers (on principle), so if anyone has a solution using the Nouveau drivers or would like to help me file a bug report I would be very interested.