# Ubuntu screen lock but sometimes can't turn back on

Tags: ubuntu, screen-lock

I use Ubuntu 22.04 and sometimes when I return to use it (the screen locked) it wakes up and asks for password. However, I have noticed that sometimes when I return to use it, the screen stays black and nothing is shown at all, even though the power and the keyboard are still on. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I used to have the same problem in `20.04` and `22.04`. I have tried so many things but nothing seemed to work. I noticed tho, that when I had an external monitor plugged in it never happened... Btw what Laptop Brand do you use? Maybe it has a problem with that hardware. I used `Schenker`.

Comment: @Pixelbog Thanks for the info, my laptop is Dell.

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing it by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 to switch to the TTY and then pressing Ctrl+Alt+F7 to switch back to the GUI, this should reload the display server.

Comment: Hi, I tried this approach but the screen still remains black. This only happens when I leave the computer unattended for a long period of time, i.e. more than one hour.

Comment: This worked on MX Linux, sorry i don't understand Ubuntu very well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my laptop(Acer Nitro AN515-45) and using Ubuntu 22.04. I found the topic and tried that [way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442057/ubuntu-18-04-wont-wake-after-screen-lock-and-blank-suspend-sleep#:%7E:text=There%20seems%20to%20be%20an%20issue%20with%20nouveau%20driver), and then this issue was resolved.
This is the way that I used to fix my laptop:

> sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Edit the value of **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX**

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"

Then run:

> sudo update-grub

You can see also this [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298198/ubuntu-20-04-doesnt-wake-up-after-suspend/1298222#1298222) if the way above does not work for you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/464594)