# Ubuntu 18.04 unable to wake from suspend

Tags: ubuntu, suspend

I am been unable to wake my ubuntu laptop everytime I put it into suspend.
3 possible signs:

- Sometimes it wake up ok
- Sometimes, it freezes at wake and show screen before it freeze.
- Sometimes it just a black screen but the keyboard backlights and laptop is running

Anyone has any idea how to solve this? I had only found similar problem faced by people [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442057/ubuntu-18-04-wont-wake-after-screen-lock-and-blank-suspend-sleep)

System:
Laptop Model: AFTERSHOCK Apex 17 (A reseller of Tongfang GK7CP7S)
Same laptop but rebrands include:

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, with Linux Kernel Version of 4.18.0-18-generic.

- Walmart OVERPOWERED 17+ Cyberpowerpc TRACER III 17 XTREME
- Cyberpowerpc TRACER III 17 XTREME VR
- Eluktronics MECH-17
- Tongfang Mechrevo X8Ti-plus
- PC Specialist 17.3" Recoil II (Europe)
- Illegear Selenite
- Clevocenter Nextcore

Comment: Finally someone else with Aftershock laptop. Their support is good but Windows only. Usually my activity light is on (suspend should be blinking) and the power button light is on. My workaround is to notice when there's some delay in the previous wakes and restart befpre the wake fails. Sometimes pressing the power button works also

Comment: I actually found out that there is a fingerprint sensor on the touchpad that it’s use to wake the computer up. Due to the abnormal size touchpad, sometimes you might accidentally scan you finger and it puts the system to sleep. To bring it back on, just need to scan again on the top left button. You sometimes see a flashing blue light (default light Color). Don’t need to panic you turn on the power and it’s black screen still.

Comment: I did this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/561796/314643
make sure to have xScreenSaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite easy. Once I updated to the lastest kernel for Linux in ubuntu, the issue goes away. I am able to boot from sleep with no issue.
Please refer to this: https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/
A fresh install of ubuntu 18.04 would also solve this issue as the latest os image has the latest Linux kernel.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=10689)  on the XFCE forum, you should monitor what happens when you suspend the computer.

To do so, you could install `xfce4-power-manager` and check that your hardware **indeed supports** suspending, sleeping, hibernating, screen locking, screen saving, display on/off switching, etc.

I personnally had trouble resuming after suspending. That answer, along with the [Power Manager documentation](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/start), helped me narrow down what I shouldn't do with my laptop. I am now able to suspend and resume as expected !

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For me, after trying everything I’ve found on the Web, what worked was to use `bbswitch` to switch to using a non-nvidia driver for normal usages, then switch to NVIDIA when needed.

References:

https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/Suspend-resume-problems-on-Ubuntu-18-04/m-p/6087331/highlight/true#M16980

https://m.youtube.com/watch?t=433s&v=5nGbWE-pvIE