# LightDM sometimes resumes with a blank display after suspend

Tags: debian, suspend, lightdm

I'm suspending my laptop very often, by manually calling `pm-suspend` command. Most of the times it works without problems.

However, sometimes it resumes with a blank screen. Either a reboot or issuing `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart` on TTY1 (Ctrl+ALT+F1) makes it work, but I loose all of my unsaved documents and working layout of course.

Is there a way to make LightDM start on TTY1 without restarting it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Root of the problem

It turns out that the exact problem was issuing a screen lock command while the laptop's lid is closed:

```
sleep 5s; physlock -d
```

Run above command and immediately close the laptop lid. Wait like 10 seconds, then open the lid. A password prompt will wait for your password input. When the correct password is entered, you'll end up with a totally blank screen.

## Actual Solution

Current workaround is running `xrandr --auto` on `TTY7`, within the same `my-suspend` script:

```
echo "Locking display"
physlock -d 

echo "suspending..."
pm-suspend

echo "Performing workaround for LightDM bug"
while :; do
    xrandr --auto && break || sleep 1s
done
```

## Answer to the original issue

When this `xrandr --auto` command is issued on another tty, it doesn't work even though `DISPLAY=:0` is set beforehand. However, the following procedure works:

1. Switch to `TTY1` (`Ctrl + Alt + F1`):
2. Issue the following command:

```
$ while :; do DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --auto && break || sleep 1s; done
```

This command will keep failing every second with the following error:

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
...
```

3. Switch to `TTY7` (`Ctrl + Alt + F7`)
4. Wait 1 second
5. Voila!

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I have to use this workaround since I upgraded Xubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. Do you know the "proper" solution? It happens for me just suspending by closing the lid which is handled by `xfce4-power-manager`.

Comment: This worked for me! I dumped the while loop into a `fix_lightdm_blackscreen.bash` in my home directory for future use.  This issue also compounds with a subsequent screensaver issue (mouse/keyboard input won't work), that I fix with `pkill --full -9 /usr/bin/xfce4-screensaver`.